# C++ embarassing question on passing iterators to functions

Tags: c++, iterator

So, given this function definition:

```
void xx(list<int> my_list, list<int>::iterator start){
   
    list<int>::iterator _start = start;
    distance(my_list.begin(),_start);
}
```

Why does the following cause `distance()` inside the function to hang?

```
list<int> L;
L.push_back(0);
L.push_back(1);

xx(L, L.begin());
```

I thought it would just be zero. Yes, I know I suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my_list` is declared as pass-by-value, it's a copy from the argument. That means, given `distance(my_list.begin(),_start);`, `my_list.begin()` and `_start` point to two different `std::list`s, the behavior is undefined.

If you change it to pass-by-reference, then both the iterators point to the same `std::list` and the code would be fine. e.g.

```
void xx(list<int>& my_list, list<int>::iterator start){
   
    list<int>::iterator _start = start;
    distance(my_list.begin(),_start);
}
```

Comment: HAHA. Wow. Been at the terminal too long today. Time for me to go to bed. Sheesh.

Comment: Please click click the green checkmark if this answers your question.